# Count missing values with rowwise and add number of missing values

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi there: I would like to add a column to a dataframe that looks like this that has the number of missing values in it.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
#Set 1 missing value
df[1,1]<-NA
df[2,1]<-NA

library(tidyverse)
df
df %>% 
#I know select is somewhat superflurous in this dataframe, but I need it in my example, so I want to be sure I get ti right
  select(var1, var2) %>% 
  is.na() %>% 
#The missing values are there. 
  head()
#How do I add the counts
df %>% 
  select(var1, var2) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(na=rowSums(is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `rowwise`. Just comment that line and your code works.

This works:

```
df %>% 
  select(var1, var2) %>% 
  mutate(na = rowSums(is.na(.)))
```

Comment: When I try that on my underlying data I get this: `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `na`.
x Input `na` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `na` is `rowSums(is.na(.))`.
ℹ Input `na` must be size 1, not 4202.
ℹ Did you mean: `na = list(rowSums(is.na(.)))` ?
ℹ The error occured in row 1.`

I'm working with labelled data. Could  that be an issue?

Comment: Possibly. Could you provide an example of the exact type of data you are working with in the question? Just a couple lines should be sufficient.

Comment: Correction: it works fine. My dataframe had been grouped rowwise in previous code. Ungrouping it worked fine. Wow. Rowwise() appears to be tricky.

Comment: Ah yes, that would do it. Good catch. Really common when working with grouping to forget to ungroup. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rowSums` directly :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(na = rowSums(is.na(select(., var1, var2))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this using `rowwise()` for sure and `mutate()` to create `Var`, which will store the number of `NA`. For row operations you can use `c_across()` evaluating the desired conditions. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Var=sum(is.na(c_across(var1:var2))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      var1    var2   Var
     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1 NA       0.990      1
 2 NA       0.509      1
 3 -0.248  -1.89       0
 4 -0.149  -0.230      0
 5 -0.808   0.421      0
 6  0.216  -1.36       0
 7 -0.319   1.50       0
 8 -0.0418  0.487      0
 9 -3.36   -2.37       0
10 -0.151  -0.0478     0
# ... with 90 more rows
```